# UsedRange.find function skipping hidden columns in the second run. Is there any property which deals with this?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find out the last column of the used range using find function. But it is skipping the last hidden columns in the second run onwards.

Answer (score 0):

set `Range.Find(LookIn:=xlFormulas)` to include hidden cells as well

[Range.Find Method Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)